# How to come out to the previous file in vi after entering a file with 'gf'?

Tags: vim

I searched for this but couldn't find it.
When using vi for a file A, if I want to go to a file B when the cursor is on file B's filename, I press 'gf' and vi opens file B. After navigating inside file B, if I want to come out to file A, what is the correct key? I know that if I press 'ctrl+o' several times, I can come back to file A, and if I do ':rewind', I can come back out to the first file that I opened with vi. But I want to know the key to come back out just one file when I went into a file using many 'gf' commands.

**ADD**
I found from the official vi manual (https://www.vi-improved.org/vimusermanual.pdf), that I can mark a global position(not local to a file) using capital letter, and can come to that position while editing another file by coming to that tag. Like `mF` in file A and the in file B `'F` to come to the mark 'F' in file A. This is usually what I want but I'm curious if I can come out just one file as in my question.

Comment: [Vi and Vim Stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) seems a better place for this question.